# How to set a non-default system sound in Pixel 4 Clock?

Tags: alarm, clock

I replaced my Pixel 2 XL with a Pixel 4 XL (both Android 10), and when I try to set an individual alarm’s sound the only choices are:

- the default system alarm sound
- a custom sound from my drive (via `+ Add new`)
- the music sounds (Youtube, Pandora, etc.)

When I go to Settings -> Sounds and Alarms, I can use the ‘Sounds’ app to select from a large number of system sounds.

**How can I have the same selection of system sounds I see in Sounds and Alarms in the Clock app?** I do not recall this ever being an issue on my Pixel 2 XL.

Things I have tried:

- resetting the Clock storage + cache
- changing the default alarm

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a recent Google Clock update from the Play store the system notification tones are available again. The change list mentions 'bug fixes' without specifics.

The 'Sounds' app is still not accessible from the Clock app, but this is good enough for my purposes.